# Mark/deletion line in Clear app

Tags: ios, line

I'm trying to figure out how the line in the middle of a word (mark/pre-deletion, alternative to checkmark) in Clear app for iPhone is made.Is it something simple just like an NSString rename or should i check drawRect ?

Comment: What have you tried? Posting your code will help people provide the help you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like drawRect is what they are using, as a string rename would apply the line to the full letter while you can see the line is being drawn pixel by pixel instead.